# Add Values to a new column (Column C) , after multiplying values of (Column B) with a constant

Tags: oracle, plsql

Need to save values of column **CHARGE** in **TAX_AMNT** after multiplying with a certain constant.

```
| Charge   |   TAX_AMNT    |  Total_AMNT|
| 50       |    null       |     null   |
| 80       |    null       |     null   |
| 90       |    null       |     null   |
| 10       |    null       |     null   |
```

Lets say, I need to multiply values in charge with constant value **0.5** , and then save values in tax_amnt , and finally have total_amnt to be charge + calculated tax_amnt.

The final table to look something like this.

```
| Charge   |   TAX_AMNT    |  Total_AMNT|
| 50       |    25         |     75     |
| 80       |    40         |     120    |
| 90       |    45         |     135    |
| 10       |    05         |     15     |
```

Comment: What is the requirement? Do you need to insert data in the two columns

Comment: Yes. In both columns.

Comment: use direct update statement.... have you tried?

Comment: Can you please tell me the update statement to use?

Comment: I downvoted this question because it doesn't show any research effort. You got some history of (homework?) questions like that, by the way. Please put in a bit of effort in finding your own answers, instead of posting an assignment here every other day.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few options.

One is to use two consecutive `UPDATE` statements:

```
update test set
  tax_amnt = charge * 0.5;

update test set
  total_amnt = charge + tax_amnt;
```

---

Another one is to do it in a single `UPDATE`:

```
update test set
  tax_amnt = charge * 0.5,
  total_amnt = (charge * 0.5) + charge;
```

---

Or, you could even use `MERGE`:

```
merge into test t
  using (select t1.charge * 0.5 tax_amnt,
           t1.charge
         from test t1
        ) x
  on (t.charge = x.charge)
when matched then update set
  t.tax_amnt = x.tax_amnt,
  t.total_amnt = x.charge + x.tax_amnt;
```

---

Although this - obviously - can be done, consider **NOT** to store the `TOTAL_AMNT` at all (i.e. drop the column). Although it is kind of *nice* having the total result in a table, it requires you to maintain its value all the time. What if you update `TAX_AMNT`? Will you remember that you have to re-calculate `TOTAL_AMNT`? The same goes for `CHARGE` and any other column which might be involved in `TOTAL_AMNT`'s value.

It is a simple matter of querying and displaying that value when you need it, e.g.

```
select tax_amnt, 
       charge, 
       tax_amnt + charge as total_amnt
from test
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update those two columns by the following UPDATE:

```
UPDATE TableName SET TAX_AMNT = (Charge * 0.5), Total_AMNT = Charge + (Charge * 0.5)
```